# File directory from string

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with my C# code. Concept: after choosing file from FileDialog, I want to write file's directory to string and later - basing on this string - I want to run file from the path, but instead I have error 'The path is not of a legal form'. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

            System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);
            label8.Text = fileToOpen;

            string sciezka = label8.Text;
            label9.Text = sciezka; 
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton6.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Proszę wybrać opcję 'Sterowanie klawiaturą.", "Uwaga!",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else if (label8.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Proszę wybrać plik do sterowania robotem.", "Uwaga!",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(sciezka);

            Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is "sciezka" used in "button3_Click_1" assigned ? "sciezka" in "button2_Click_2" is a local variable to the method. Should have thrown a compile time error

Comment: Your title and your question text talk about a file's directory.  I don't see you doing anything with a directory in your code.  This code (`System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);`) in your first handler is useless.  I don't know what `sciezka` means, but having it as a useless local variable in the first handler and then having a different variable with the same name in the second handler is confusing.  What is the point of the second handler.  Is it somehow related to the first?

Comment: @Flydog57 Actually I just figured out how to fix this. Second handler was necessary to check if everything is working. I used this:

`{Process wczytaj = new Process();
wczytaj.StartInfo.FileName = label8.Text;
                wczytaj.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                wczytaj.Start();} `

Answer (score 4):

`sciezka` is your filename and you are getting the full path to it with:

```
Path.GetFullPath(sciezka)
```

However, `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` expects a directory, not a path to a file.

[ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> When the UseShellExecute property is false, gets or sets the working
>   directory for the process to be started. When UseShellExecute is true,
>   gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.

Answer (score -1):

```
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(sciezka);
startInfo.FileName = sciezka;
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```